# Could not deserialize key data on decoding JWT python

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, jwt, encode

I am using [pyjwt](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io) library for decoding the JWT token. I got this error when I am decoding. The code was given in the documantation.

```
import jwt

encoded_jwt='''eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG......'''
secret=b''''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIFRjCCBC6gAwIBAgIQCIdSGhpikQCjOIY154XoqzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBN
......
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''

print(jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, secret , algorithms=['RS256']))
```

> raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.") ValueError: Could
>   not deserialize key data.

Could You please help me in resolving it beacuse when I use this it in the [JWT](https://jwt.io/) website it's working.

This is the full error log..

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py",
>   line 205, in prepare_key
>       key = load_pem_private_key(key, password=None, backend=default_backend())   File
>   "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py",
>   line 20, in load_pem_private_key
>       return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py",
>   line 1014, in load_pem_private_key
>       password,   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py",
>   line 1233, in _load_key
>       self._handle_key_loading_error()   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py",
>   line 1291, in _handle_key_loading_error
>       raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.") ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/JWTsample/sample.py", line 45, in
>   
>       print(jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, secret , algorithms=['RS256']))   File
>   "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py",
>   line 93, in decode
>       jwt, key=key, algorithms=algorithms, options=options, **kwargs   File
>   "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py",
>   line 157, in decode
>       key, algorithms)   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py",
>   line 221, in _verify_signature
>       key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py",
>   line 207, in prepare_key
>       key = load_pem_public_key(key, backend=default_backend())   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py",
>   line 24, in load_pem_public_key
>       return backend.load_pem_public_key(data)   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py",
>   line 1040, in load_pem_public_key
>       self._handle_key_loading_error()   File "/home/sathiyakugan/PycharmProjects/Python/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py",
>   line 1291, in _handle_key_loading_error
>       raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.") ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @stovfl No it's different problem

Comment: You appear to have a typo. One extra apostrophe in your public key, right at the start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some issues in the pyjwt library. and you must get the public key from the certificate.

I used   `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem  > pubkey.pem`

then from the public key I could easily decode it using authlib library.

```
from authlib.specs.rfc7519 import jwt

encoded_jwt='''eyJ0eXAiOiJ....'''
secret=b'''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
......
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''
claims = jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, secret)
print(claims)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you get this error double check your public key is exactly right, new lines are important.

```
key = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
<main key here>
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''
```

Comment: This is really helpful, it should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

It's a good idea to use your RSA keys with OpenSSL:

```
openssl genrsa -out jwt-key 4096
openssl rsa -in jwt-key -pubout > jwt-key.pub
```

Reference: [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/json-web-tokens-with-public-key-signatures/page/2#comments)

**Updated Text:**

It seems you're encountering a key deserialization problem with the PyJWT library. This issue often arises from an incompatible or incorrectly formatted key. To resolve this, I suggest generating a new RSA key pair using OpenSSL. Here's a step-by-step explanation:

1. **Generating the RSA Private Key:**

   - Command: `openssl genrsa -out jwt-key 4096`
   - This command uses OpenSSL to create an RSA private key.
   - `genrsa` generates the RSA key.
   - `-out jwt-key` defines the output filename for the private key.
   - `4096` is the key size, offering a balance between security and performance.
2. **Extracting the Public Key:**

   - Command: `openssl rsa -in jwt-key -pubout > jwt-key.pub`
   - This command extracts the public key from the generated private key.
   - `-in jwt-key` specifies the input file, the private key from the first step.
   - `-pubout` signals the extraction of the public key.
   - `jwt-key.pub` is where the public key will be saved.

By using these commands, you'll generate a new RSA key pair. The private key (`jwt-key`) is for signing the JWT, and the public key (`jwt-key.pub`) is for verifying the signature. Remember to securely store the private key and only share the public key.

After generating these keys, update your Python code to use the new keys, ensuring the public key is read in the format expected by the PyJWT library. This approach should solve the deserialization issue with your current key.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this was the solution for my problem.
Thanks, and recommend answer (although I did not check the others)

Answer (score 15):

Use the [authlib](https://authlib.org/) library, I never managed to decode keycloak tokens with `pyjwt`.
You need a `public_key`, I assume you have it.

```
from authlib.jose import jwt
key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' + public_key + '\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
key_binary = key.encode('ascii')

try:
    claims = jwt.decode(encoded,key_binary)
    claims.validate()
    #do some logic here
    #...
```

ProTip: you may grab the public key easily from your auth server (in my case Keycloak) at some endpoint:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/your_realm'
with  urllib.request.urlopen(url) as r:
    response = r.read()
    public_key = json.loads(response)['public_key']
```

Comment: "I never managed to decode keycloak tokens with pyjwt" I'm late to the party here, but had a similar issue using pyjwt to validate JWTs from Keycloak. I finally realized it's because pyjwt is expecting the PUBLIC-KEY value only (not a full PEM certificate). I got it to work by converting the x509 cert which Keycloak provides into a PEM file (by wrapping it in "-----BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE-----" lines), and using the following openssl command to extract the PUBLIC-KEY value:  `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in certificate.pem`. The resulting public key output then works with pyjwt.

Comment: FWIW: https://renzolucioni.com/verifying-jwts-with-jwks-and-pyjwt/

Answer (score 11):

How did you encode your jwt? Use one of the approaches below

**Encoding & Decoding Tokens with RS256 (RSA)**

```
encoded = jwt.encode({'some': 'payload'}, private_key, algorithm='RS256')
decoded = jwt.decode(encoded, public_key, algorithms='RS256')
```

**Reading the Claimset without Validation**

```
jwt.decode(encoded, verify=False)
{u'some': u'payload'}
```

Or use same secret to encode and decode the jwt, one of the approach should work. In my case I used `jwt.decode(token, verify=False)` because my server has already did the signature validation for me, I only need to get the claimset.

Comment: This is not working for me, It says `ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.` on encoding data.

Comment: Which one is not working for you the decode method with a public key or without the public key

Comment: In my case the issue was with encoding, we can encode with the above flow but we need to load private key properly, I found this on : https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/320, after this I was able to do encode and decode.

Answer (score 3):

For `pyjwt 2.8.0`, it worked for me when using `options={"verify_signature": False}` instead of `verify=False`

```
jwt.decode(token.encode(), options={"verify_signature": False})
```

Answer (score 2):

MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 Python 2.7.16.

This solved the problem in my case

```
pip install cryptography==2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem was the fact that you are using certificate you can just extract public / private key from the certificate:

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate

cert_str = b"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIIDETCCAfm..."
cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_str)
public_key = cert_obj.public_key()
private_key = cert_obj.private_key()
```

Source: https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, there were spaces in the key (silly IDE) which caused this issue, make sure that's not the case with you

Answer (score 0):

save the public key into the file and pass the path and use that.

1. public_key = open(path).read()
2. payload = jwt.decode(token,
   public_key, algorithms=['RS256'])

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was setting the jwt verify signature to false:

```
import jwt 

token = st_javascript('''localStorage.getItem("some_token")''') # fetch your token of interest
decoded = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False}) # decode the token
```

Note: This bypasses JWT verification and should only be used if you don't care wether the JWT is cryptographically invalid or valid.

For more info you can view the jwt [documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#reading-the-claimset-without-validation).